# How to perform unit conversions within an XML file

Tags: python, xml, powershell, xslt

I have an xml output file with the basic structure (important elements expanded):

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type= "text/xsl" href="QRevStylesheet.xsl"?>
<Channel QRevFilename="20201222_193117_416_QRev" QRevVersion="QRev 4.16">
    <SiteInformation>
    <QA>
    <Instrument>
    <Processing>
    <Transect>
    <Transect>
    <Transect>
        <Filename type="char">8100_DM_20201222_1_003.PD0</Filename>
        <StartDateTime type="char">12/22/2020 19:24:09</StartDateTime>
        <EndDateTime type="char">12/22/2020 19:27:34</EndDateTime>
        <Discharge>
            <Top type="double" unitsCode="cms">4.295</Top>
            <Middle type="double" unitsCode="cms">8.816</Middle>
            <Bottom type="double" unitsCode="cms">1.205</Bottom>
            <Left type="double" unitsCode="cms">0.101</Left>
            <Right type="double" unitsCode="cms">0.415</Right>
            <Total type="double" unitsCode="cms">14.832</Total>
            <MovingBedPercentCorrection type="double">0.00</MovingBedPercentCorrection>
        </Discharge>
        <Edge>
            <StartEdge type="char">Right</StartEdge>
            <RectangularEdgeMethod type="char">Fixed</RectangularEdgeMethod>
            <VelocityMethod type="char">MeasMag</VelocityMethod>
            <LeftType type="char">Triangular</LeftType>
            <LeftEdgeCoefficient type="double">0.3535</LeftEdgeCoefficient>
            <LeftDistance type="double" unitsCode="m">2.1336</LeftDistance>
            <LeftNumberEnsembles type="double">10</LeftNumberEnsembles>
            <RightType type="char">Triangular</RightType>
            <RightEdgeCoefficient type="double">0.3535</RightEdgeCoefficient>
            <RightDistance type="double" unitsCode="m">3.3528</RightDistance>
            <RightNumberEnsembles type="double">10</RightNumberEnsembles>
        </Edge>
```

The units of this output file are in metric (meters and cubic meters per second).   I would like an output in imperial/English units, but I'm having trouble with writing a Stylesheet (xslt) file that will produce a 1-to-1 file with only the units and unit names converted.   Would python or powershell be a better choice?

Comment: Can you close the open declarations or remove them so I can parse it with python without errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way you could do the conversion using XSLT. The factors I used would need to be checked, but this shows the basic principle.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Match any element that has a unitsCode attribute -->
  <xsl:template match="*[@unitsCode]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@type"/>
      <xsl:choose>
        <!-- cm^2 to inch^2 -->
        <xsl:when test="@unitsCode='cms'">
          <xsl:attribute name="unitsCode">ins</xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:value-of select=". div 6.452"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <!-- meter to inch -->
        <xsl:when test="@unitsCode='m'">
          <xsl:attribute name="unitsCode">in</xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:value-of select=". *  39.37"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <!-- Case where the conversion is not defined, leave as is -->
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:copy-of select="@unitsCode"/>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93nwMoX